# JFrame gets resized and ScrollBars are not visible

Tags: java, swing

I have designed a Swing form. It consists of a `JScrollPane` that itself contains another `JPanel`. Due to some UI event a `Component` gets appended to this `JPanel`. Its simply like a message box, in which messages gets appended to the list as they arrive. 
The question is how to make the change onto this `JPanel` visible. To, achieve this, I simple call the `JFrame#pack()` method. But calling this resizes my frame to the size of container, ignoring the `prefferedSize, and maximumSize` bound I initially set. And Scroll Bars also don't get Visible, simply the frame gets bigger in height as component gets appended to the panel. I want that my Frame should remain in its initial size, and scrollbars should come into action, when total size of component exceeds the size of frame. Where am I going wrong ? Please Help.
This is my initial screen:
[image]

This screen is when component gets added:
[image]

Comment: can you add a screen-shot of that?

Comment: where is the code, you all explained the theory part. Please do provide code.

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits I'm using netbeans IDE. code is generated bu IDE, should I upload that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add components to a panel the general code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
```

The revalidate() method will recalculate the preferred size of the panel. If the preferred size is greater than the size of the scrollpane then scrollbars will appear.

Of course you must be using layout managers for this functionality to happen automatically.

Comment: can you pls explain why `JFrame#pack()` ignore the `maximumSize`??

Comment: @Sanjay depends of used LayoutManager, most of them pretty ignore XxxSize, excepting BoxLayout